# ¿Como acceder a un valor de un atributo desde afuera, que se encuentra dentro de un bucle *ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7

```
<ng-template ngbPanelContent>
  <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Nro de Expediente</th>
        <th scope="col">Causa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let expediente of expedientes; index as i">
        <input id="tagcontent" type="hidden" />
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <th scope="row">{{expediente.ranroexpediente}}</th>
        <td>{{expediente.racausaexpediente}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-space" routerLink="/expediente/{{expediente.idexpediente}}">Agregar expediente</a>
  <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-space" routerLink="/historial/expediente.idexpediente">historial</a>
</ng-template>
```

Hola chicos que tal, tengo la siguiente duda, como verán tengo una tabla donde cargo con un *ngfor una serie de campos traídos de un servicio, el problema que quiero solucionar es el siguiente: 
en la línea:

Agregar expediente

Angular me da un error diciendo que no tengo acceso a expediente.idexpediente, eso está claro, ya que esta fuera del ngfor, sé que podría resolver el problema colocándolo al elemento dentro del bucle pero eso no es lo que quiero hacer. ¿Podrían explicarme como acceder a ese expediente.idexpediente fuera del bucle? tal vez definir una variable y que la misma tome el valor de expediente.idexpediente, pero no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Por qué tu servicio no trae el IdExpediente en cada expediente del arreglo?

Comment: Eso no es posible. El `IdExpediente` es una variable que existe solo en el scope del `ngFor`. Tampoco entiendo muy bien lo del botón Agregar expediente porque no deberías tener tantos botones como expedientes?

Comment: solamente use una parte del codigo. Esa tabla esta dentro de un accordion y por cada persona voy mostrando dentro del acordion una tabla con esta información. Por lo tanto cada acordion tiene un boton de agregar expediende donde al hacer click me llevaria a una vista expediente pasandle el id de la persona en cuestion. Lo que no logro es poder tener ese id fuera del ngfor.

Comment: Hola, lo que usted quiere hacer no es posible, pero en cambio la solucion que realmente tiene sentido es agregar las etiquetas <a> dentro del ciclo en una columna adicional y de esa manera puede generar acciones usando la data dentro del ngFor.